# YouTube: get number of watch later items

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm building a dashboard (in php) for all of my relevant data and I also want to display the number of my items in the YouTube "watch later" playlist.

I know there is no way to use the YouTube API for this but maybe there is someone with an idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your servers support for cross-platform support and the Youtube terms of service, you could write an effective data scraper in PHP. At least their [robots.txt](https://www.youtube.com/robots.txt) seems to allow for you to request [Watch Later](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=WL) (which was surprisingly difficult to find by itself).

This page then has a field

```
<yt-formatted-string class="style-scope ytd-playlist-sidebar-primary-info-renderer">
    655 videos
</yt-formatted-string>
```

which you can let the code read. While you're at it, you might even want to add the first few entries to your dashboard too.